# Can stargazer output both SE and CI?

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I am brand new to using R, but have discovered Stargazer as an attractive way to display regression output. My question is whether there is a way for Stargazer to output BOTH SE of coefficients and CI? I realize this may be statistically redundant, but would be useful.

This gives me coefficients, SE, and p:

```r
stargazer(mylogit, type = "text", report = "vc*sp")
```

This gives me coefficients, CI, and p:

```r
stargazer(mylogit, type = "text", ci = TRUE, report = "vc*sp")
```

Any way to get both SE and CI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add standard errors \*and\* confidence intervals in a single column using Stargazer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112956/can-i-add-standard-errors-and-confidence-intervals-in-a-single-column-using-st)